# Question about the OPE of a hermitian and an anti-hermitian operator

Tags: operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory

In Polchinski's string theory volume 1 book, he defines the $X^\mu(z,\bar{z})$ coordinate to be hermitian and we have that $\partial X^\mu(z, \bar{z})$ is anti-hermitian: $(X^\mu)^\dagger = X^\mu$ and $(\partial X^\mu)^\dagger = - \partial X^\mu$. Also, we have the following OPE between those fields

$$X^\mu (z)\partial X^\nu(w) =  \frac{1}{z-w} \tag{1}$$

But taking the hermitian conjugate of the above equation, we see that

$$\left(X^\mu (z)\partial X^\nu(w)\right)^\dagger = - X^\mu (z)\partial X^\nu(w) \quad\text{and}\quad \left(\frac{1}{z-w}\right)^\dagger = \frac{1}{z-w},\tag{2}$$

which contradicts equation $(1)$ when both $z$ and $w$ are real. Can someone clarify where is the mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: Does the book say $(\partial X^\mu)^\dagger = -\partial X^\mu$? That doesn't seem right. The derivative $\partial$ by itself is not (a representation of) an operator on a Hilbert space. It's the derivative *of* an operator on a Hilbert space.

Comment: In chapter 2, he writes the vertex operator for the photon as  $  i\partial X^\mu$, and this should be real, so that $\partial X^\mu$ should be anti-hermitian.

Comment: @Slayer147  $(\partial X^\mu)^\dagger = - \partial X^\mu$  is not true. An explicit expression for  $\partial X^\mu$ (equation 2.7.1 in Polchinski texbook) can be written and it also can be noticed that is not hermitian nor anti-hermitian (use $(\alpha_{n}^{\mu})^{\dagger}= \alpha_{-n}^{\mu}$). Now, it is true that a photon state for the open string is written as $\zeta \alpha_{-1} |1>$ (where $\zeta$ is the polarization vector) but the only requirement that the operator $\zeta \alpha_{-1}$ must obey is unitarity (which is actually satisfied).

Comment: @Slayer147 My question is: why $i\partial X^{\mu}$ ($\rightarrow \alpha_{-1}^{\mu}$ under the operator-state map) should be "real" (equal to its adjoint)?

Comment: The notion of a "hermitian" operator doesn't really make sense on a euclidean worldsheet (which is why Polchinski defines the notion of euclidean adjoint instead). To take the euclidean adjoint of a vertex operator you complex conjugate all *explicit* factors of $i=\sqrt{-1}$ (and if there is non-trivial winding there is an additional phase).  (I also don't understand where your eqn (2) came from.)

Comment: @RamiroHum-Sah Sorry, but what I mean by $\alpha_{-1}^\mu$ being real, should be more specific stated in the BPZ + Hermitian conjugation sense, because $\text{BPZ}((\alpha_{-1}^\mu)^\dagger)=\text{BPZ}(\alpha_1^\mu)= \alpha_{-1}$. But the point of my question is that we need the i in the vertex operator for the photon $i \partial X^\mu$, because there is an i in the mode expansion for $\partial X^\mu$, so that both i's cancel and the vertex operator do not change sign under hermitian conjugation.

Comment: @Wakabaloola Maybe it does not make sense to take the adjoint of the expression for the OPE that I wrote, only expressing this OPE in terms of the commutation of the modes. Can you specify where he defines the Euclidean adjoint?

Comment: @Slayer147 Polchinski, vol.1, p. 202-3, 336.  

E.g., the Euclidean adjoint of $i\partial_z Xe^{ik\cdot X}$ is $-i\partial_z Xe^{-ik\cdot X}$, whereas the Euclidean adjoint of $\zeta_{\mu\nu}\partial_z X^\mu \partial_{\bar{z}}X^\nu e^{ik\cdot X}$ is $\zeta_{\mu\nu}^*\partial_z X^\mu \partial_{\bar{z}}X^\nu e^{-ik\cdot X}$, etc. You can check that this is necessary in order to get positive norm states. When there is winding there is also a factor of $(-)^{N-\bar{N}}$ for level numbers $N,\bar{N}$ (independently of cocycles which involve extra phases). (For ghosts it's a bit more complicated).

Comment: @Slayer147 Write $z=e^{-i(\sigma+i\tau)}$. You can define Euclidean conjugation as a composition of three maps, $C\circ T\circ U$, where $U$ is inversion, $U:z\rightarrow 1/z$; $T$ is Euclidean time reversal, $T:z\rightarrow 1/\bar{z}$; and $C$ is complex conjugation, $C:z\rightarrow \bar{z}=z^*$. (Example: check that although $C\circ T\circ U:z\rightarrow z$, the map $C\circ T\circ U$ acts non-trivially on local operators, e.g., $C\circ T\circ U:\,:e^{ik\cdot X}:\rightarrow :e^{-ik\cdot X}:$. You can use that it transforms as a primary under conformal transformations.)

Comment: p.s. Incidentally, this prescription can be derived from cutting open the string path integral across some (trivial or non-trivial homology) cycle of your Riemann surface.